# Need to read file from path to start cluster in nodejs

Tags: node.js, file, node-modules, node-commander

I am making a small project in which I need to start a cluster from the server file and that file I need to get from the commander cli argument.

program.start is to get the file name.

```
let filePath = fs.readFile(process.cwd() + "\\"+`${program.start}`, function(err, data)
   {
       if(err)
           console.log(err)
       else
           console.log("completed");
   });           
    if(cluster.isMaster){
        const cpus = os.cpus().length;

      console.log('Forking for ${cpus} CPUs');
      for (let i = 0; i<cpus;i++){
          cluster.fork();
      }
    }
    else{
        require(filePath);
    }
```

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: missing path
I am stuck need help in this.

Comment: Do you know which line is failing? Does `program.start` have the expected value? Is the failure occurring in the master or in the fork?

Comment: program.start value comes from cli args which is a filename and trying to use a filename with the current path to start the cluster.

Comment: You are calling `readfile` which will read the file contents. But then you pass it to `require` which takes a path to load. Perhaps you don't need the `readfile`, just pass the file path to `require`? (Guessing at what you are trying to do sorry.)